# Python: Size of (large) dict 10 times smaller when pickled

Tags: python, dictionary, integer, size, pickle

I'm trying to understand what's going in internally with python in the following.

Situation (Python3 on debian):

- A (large) dict that has integers as keys (running from zero) and tuples as values.
- The elements of the tuple are ALL integers (randomly from zero to the number of the largest key).
- All tuples have exactly 30 elements.

Problem:

- The pickled dict is significantly (approx. 10 times!) smaller on my harddisk than the size of the single elements should represent in memory.

Details:

- The size of an integer is 28 bytes (except < 0 > which is just 24 bytes).
- The size of a tuple is dependent on the number of elements it contains; assuming 30 elements it is 288 bytes.
- The size of a dictionary is dependent on the number of elements it contains; assuming 1000 elements it is 49248 bytes.
- Given the situation above, 1000 elements in the dict and assuming the number < 0 > appears 29 times in the tuples I get:

> size of the integers in the tuples: 28 x 30 x 1000 - 4 x 29 = 839,884 bytes
> size of the tuples: 288 x 1000 = 288,000 bytes
> size of the keys: 28 x 1000 - 4 (the first key is zero) = 27,996 bytes
> size of the dict with 1000 elements: 49,248 bytes
> Sum of this all = 1,205,128 bytes

- Now I pickle this dict to harddisk as a binary file and I actually get 91,207 bytes as the size of the file.

So my question is now: what is going on here?
Is the pickling "compressing" the integers to just what the bits (or something like that)  are? The number < 1000 > for example can be represented with just 10 bits and would fit into 2 bytes (instead of 28).

Code that might be useful:

```
import os
import sys
import random

max_key = 1000
zeros = 0
theoretical_size = 0
the_dict = {}

for i in range(max_key):
    the_tuple = tuple()

    ii = 0
    while ii < 30:
        number = random.randint(0, (max_key - 1))
        if number not in the_tuple:
            the_tuple += (number, )
            theoretical_size += sys.getsizeof(number)
            ii += 1

            if not number:
                zeros += 1

    theoretical_size += sys.getsizeof(the_tuple)
    theoretical_size += sys.getsizeof(i)

    the_dict[i] = the_tuple

theoretical_size += sys.getsizeof(the_dict)

outfile = '/path/to/outfile/outfilename'
with open(outfile, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(the_dict, f)

print("           zeros:", zeros)
print("theoretical size:", theoretical_size)
print("      Calculated:", 28*30*max_key - 4*zeros + 288*max_key + 28*max_key - 4 + sys.getsizeof(the_dict))
print("         On disk:", os.path.getsize(outfile))
```

Comment: Pickled objects are serialized, thus the decrease in footprint when written to storage.

Comment: Great, that's the answer than.